# Assert Text Error, AssertionError: No text to speak

Tags: python, sql

I'm working on a project that uses voice assistant to query information stored in my sql database but I keep getting this error.
The voice assistant is able to display the instructions and commands but cannot query the information from mysql.
Such that if you tell it to "Show Databases" it brings up the assertion error.

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-055b51b54c64> in <module>
     62             txt=query_engine(str(guess["transcription"]) + " Task Achieved successfuly !")
     63             print(txt)
---> 64             speak(txt)
     65         else:
     66             print("Sorry, I can't perform what you have said . Please try again! ")#.format(word))

<ipython-input-4-66497e4d6f75> in speak(text)
      1 def speak(text):
----> 2     tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en",slow = False)
      3     filename = str(random.choice(list(text)))+str(random.randint(1,100))+".mp3"
      4     tts.save(filename)
      5     playsound.playsound(filename)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py in __init__(self, text, tld, lang, slow, lang_check, pre_processor_funcs, tokenizer_func)
    132 
    133         # Text
--> 134         assert text, "No text to speak"
    135         self.text = text
    136 

AssertionError: No text to speak
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am using python and mysql

```
import os
import time
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import mysql.connector as sql
import random
import pandas as pd


def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en",slow = False)
    filename = str(random.choice(list(text)))+str(random.randint(1,100))+".mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)

def connection(status):
    if status:
        resp=("Yes! your Connection Estabilished .\n"
              "Now go head to explore your data world ! \n")
        print(resp)
        speak(resp)
        print(commands)
    else:
        print("There is a problem with Data Server, I am unable to reach it.")
        speak("There is a problem with Data Server, I am unable to reach it.")        
        exit(0)
def db_connect():
    try:

        db_connection = sql.connect(host='localhost', database='', user='root', password='ecell123')
        if db_connection:
            return(db_connection)
        else:
            # resp="Oh! sorry, something went Wrong! while estabilshing the Connection with Database"
            # print(resp)
            # speak(resp)
            return(False)
        
    except:
        connection(False)

def query_engine(query):
    
    def show_dbs():
            if 'connect to database'  not in recorded:
                speak('Please wait ! I am estabilishing secure connection to database !')
                print('Please wait ! I am estabilishing secure connection to database !')
                if db_connect() :
                    recorded.append('connect to database')
                    sce=db_connect()
                    db_cursor = sce.cursor()    
                    db_cursor.execute('show databases')
                    table_rows = db_cursor.fetchall()
                    df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
                    speak("Here is the list of Databases available in your store. ")
                    print(df)
                    return df.values.tolist()
            else:
                if db_connect() is not False:
            #global db_connection
                    sce=db_connect()
                    db_cursor = sce.cursor()    
                    db_cursor.execute('show databases')
                    table_rows = db_cursor.fetchall()
                    df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
                    speak("Here is the list of Databases available in your store. ")
                    print(df)
                    return df.values.tolist()
                else:
                    exit(0)
    def db_select():
        rows=show_dbs()
        l=[]
        for i in range(len(rows)):
            l.append(rows[i][0])
        #print("rows",l)
        print("Please Select any one of the given databases")
        speak("You can select any one of the given databases")
        return l
    def db_selected():
        rows=db_select()
        for i in range(5):
            dbname=ask()
            #print(rows)
            if dbname in  rows :
                print("Yes ,", dbname, " Database is in given list !")
                speak("Yes ,"+ dbname + " Database is in given list !")
                break
            else:
                print(dbname, " Not matched in given databases list")
                speak(dbname+ " Not matched in given databases list")

        db_connection2 = sql.connect(host='localhost', database=dbname, user='root', password='ecell123') 
        if db_connection2:
            print("{} Selected. Now you can access the TABLES".format(dbname))
            speak(str(dbname)+ " Selected . Now you can access the TABLES. ")
            return db_connection2, dbname
    def show_tables():
        conn,dtbname=db_selected()
        if conn is not False:
            #global db_connection
                    
                    db_cursor = conn.cursor()    
                    db_cursor.execute('show tables')
                    table_rows1 = db_cursor.fetchall()
                    df1 = pd.DataFrame(table_rows1)
                    speak("Here is the list of Tables available in "+ dtbname+ " Database.")
                    print(df1)
                    return df1.values.tolist(),conn
        else:
                    exit(0)        

    if query == 'connect to database':
        if query not in recorded:
            if db_connect():
                connection(True)
                recorded.append(query)
        else:
            print(' Hey! Cool. I already did that :)- ')
            speak(' Hey! Cool. I already did that !')

    if query == 'show databases':
        show_dbs()
    if query == 'select database':
        db_selected()
    if query == "show tables":
        show_tables()
    if query =='show table data':
        table,conn=show_tables()
        tables=[]
        for i in range(len(table)):
            tables.append(table[i][0])
        print("tables",tables)
        for i in range(5):
            tbname=ask()
            #print(rows)
            if tbname in  tables :
                print("Right! ", tbname, " table is in given list")
                speak("Right! "+tbname+" Table is in given list")
                break
            else:
                print(tbname," Not matched in given Tables list")
                speak(tbname +" Not matched in given Tables list")

        db_cursor = conn.cursor() 
        qry= 'select * from '+tbname
        db_cursor.execute(qry)
        table_rows2 = db_cursor.fetchall()
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(table_rows2)
        speak("Here is the Data of the "+ tbname+" Table available in your database.")
        print(df2)
    return query 

def recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer, microphone):
    """Transcribe speech from recorded from `microphone`.
    Returns a dictionary with three keys:
    "success": a boolean indicating whether or not the API request was
               successful
    "error":   `None` if no error occured, otherwise a string containing
               an error message if the API could not be reached or
               speech was unrecognizable
    "transcription": `None` if speech could not be transcribed,
               otherwise a string containing the transcribed text
    """
    # check that recognizer and microphone arguments are appropriate type
    if not isinstance(recognizer, sr.Recognizer):
        raise TypeError("`recognizer` must be `Recognizer` instance")

    if not isinstance(microphone, sr.Microphone):
        raise TypeError("`microphone` must be `Microphone` instance")

    # adjust the recognizer sensitivity to ambient noise and record audio
    # from the microphone
    with microphone as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    # set up the response object
    response = {
        "success": True,
        "error": None,
        "transcription": None
    }

    # try recognizing the speech in the recording
    # if a RequestError or UnknownValueError exception is caught,
    #     update the response object accordingly
    try:
        response["transcription"] = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
    except sr.RequestError:
        # API was unreachable or unresponsive
        response["success"] = False
        response["error"] = "API unavailable"
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        # speech was unintelligible
        response["error"] = "Unable to recognize speech"

    return response


instructions = (
        "Hi There! I am your Database Interaction Voice Assistant:\n"
        
        "I love to help you to get the data available in Database storages.\n"
        "I'm pleased to say, You can check the following example instructions.\n "
    )

commands=(
    " --- Connect to Database \n"
    " --- Show Databases \n"
    " --- Select Database [Name] \n"
    " --- Show TABLES \n"
    " --- Show TABLE Data \n"
    " --- Say abort or end or terminate to exit \n"
    )
# show instructions and wait 2 seconds before starting the game

print(instructions)
print(commands)
speak(instructions)
db_connect()
time.sleep(2)
```

```
def ask () :
    recognizer1 = sr.Recognizer()
    microphone1 = sr.Microphone()
    for j in range(5):
            speak("I'm Listening ....")
            print("Speak : I'm Listening .... for Table/DB Name ")
            guess = recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer1, microphone1)
            if guess["transcription"]:
                break
            if not guess["success"]:
                break
            speak("Sorry. I didn't catch that. What did you say?")
            print("I didn't catch that. What did you say?\n")

        # if there was an error, stop the game
    if guess["error"]:
            print("ERROR: {}".format(guess["error"]))
            exit()
        # show the user the transcription
    print("You said: {}".format(guess["transcription"]))
    return(guess['transcription'].lower())
if __name__ == "__main__":           
    recorded=[]
    queries=[ 'connect to database',
        "show databases",
        "select database",
        "show tables",
        "show table data"]
    # create recognizer and mic instances
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    microphone = sr.Microphone()

    while True:

        for j in range(5):
            speak("Please Speak. I'm Listening ....")
            print("Speak {}. I'm Listening .... ".format(j+1))
            guess = recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer, microphone)
            if guess["transcription"]:
                break
            if not guess["success"]:
                break
            speak("Sorry. I didn't catch that. What did you say?")
            print("I didn't catch that. What did you say?\n")

        # if there was an error, stop the game
        if guess["error"]:
            print("ERROR: {}".format(guess["error"]))
            break

        # show the user the transcription
        print("You said: {}".format(guess["transcription"]))

        # determine if guess is correct and if any attempts remain
        if guess["transcription"] is not None:
            guess_is_correct = guess["transcription"].lower() in queries # "Connect to Database".lower()
            if guess["transcription"].lower()  in ('abort', 'end', 'terminate'):
                speak( " Thanks for Using. Have a Good day !")
                print( " Thanks for Using. Have a Good day !")
                break
        if guess_is_correct:
            txt=query_engine(guess["transcription"]) 
            print(txt)
            speak(txt)
           
        else:
            print("Sorry, I can't perform what you have said . Please try again! ")#.format(word))
            speak("Sorry, I can't perform what you have said . Please try again!")
```

Comment: just before doing `speak(txt)` you do `print(txt)`. Can you post what is inside txt? What's being printed?

Comment: I see no SQL above, is this really related to the SQL _language_?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki It's supposed to print whatever you query from mysql, but currently  it prints "none"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: well, if you do `assert None, "No text to speak"` the assert will fail. You cannot say None being None not a string but a None object. The problem here is probably that the query engine returns None because `guess["transcription"]` doesn't exist. Can you do `print(guess["transcription"])` and see what it prints?`

Comment: @SimplyJeff why are you setting txt as `query_engine(str(guess["transcription"]) + " Task Achieved successfuly !")` 
shouldn't it be:
`query_engine(str(guess["transcription"])) + " Task Achieved successfuly !"`
Notice the brackets

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki print(guess["transcription"])  prints "show databases"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if guess_is_correct:
    txt=query_engine(guess["transcription"]) 
    print(txt)
    speak(txt)
```

"speak" expects "txt" to be a string and not none.
Check what does `query_engine(guess["transcription"])` returns.

If `print(guess["transcription"]) prints "show databases"` then you're passing a list and not a string

Comment: what is the proposed solution here? thanks.

Comment: Iterate over the list and pass the strings contained within that list to speak function one by one

Comment: this worked well! Thanks, I appreciate.